# SharePoint 2013 - Get a list of all users in JS in apps

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I found the code to show the current logged in user in the example from MS.

How do I display the list of ALL users using JS?

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();

// This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is needed to use the SharePoint object model
$(document).ready(function () {
getUserName();
});

//This function prepares, loads, and then executes a SharePoint query to get the current users information
function getUserName() {
context.load(user);
context.executeQueryAsync(onGetUserNameSuccess, onGetUserNameFail);
}

// This function is executed if the above call is successful
// It replaces the contents of the 'message' element with the user name
function onGetUserNameSuccess() {
$('#message').text('Hello ' + user.get_title());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to decide on a timeframe as to consider the user being actually logged in (HTTP is stateless). And you can log the currentuser information for that timeframe (using the code you have) and consider them as your currently logged in user list. You can also use a web analytics / logging tool..[something like this](http://spcurrentusers.codeplex.com/).

If you just want the list of all the users in all the groups regardless they are considered logged in or not, than you can use this:

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection ';

function retrieveAllUsersAllGroups() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    this.collGroup = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
    clientContext.load(collGroup);
    clientContext.load(collGroup, 'Include(Users)');

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    var userInfo = '';

    var groupEnumerator = collGroup.getEnumerator();
    while (groupEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oGroup = groupEnumerator.get_current();
        var collUser = oGroup.get_users();
        var userEnumerator = collUser.getEnumerator();
        while (userEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oUser = userEnumerator.get_current();
            this.userInfo += '\nGroup ID: ' + oGroup.get_id() + 
                '\nGroup Title: ' + oGroup.get_title() + 
                '\nUser: ' + oUser.get_title() + 
                '\nLogin Name: ' + oUser.get_loginName();
        }
    }

    alert(userInfo);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Look [through here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185012(v=office.14).aspx) for more examples.

Comment: this is now what I want to achieve. I need a way to get all users from sharepoint. They don't have to be logged in.

Comment: thanks, that looks exactly what I need, but I get this error:  Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.